# Generated boolean sub-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

So in class we came across the next definition:
Let B be a boolean algebra and E a subset of B, let A be a boolean sub-algebra of B that contains E, we will say that A is generated by E if for every D, D a subalgebra of B, such that E is a subset of D, then A is a subalgebra of D.

And we'll say that A= gen(E).

I find this definition to be very confusing, so I have two main questions:

1. wouldn't this definition imply that the empty set generates every boolean algebra? Also wouldn't 1 or 0 always be a generator of every subalgebra for every algebra?
2. why does A have to be a subalgebra of every D?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It did cross my mind that professor got this wrong, would you please refer me to the proper definition?

Comment: The subalgebra generated by $E$ is the intersection of all boolean subalgebras that contain $E$.  This definition works whenever substructures are closed under arbitrary intersections.

Comment: @AnneBauval the empty set is a subset of B, A also contains the empty set, and the empty set is contained in any arbitrary family of subalgebras, doesn't the empty set always accomplish the definition, for any subalgebra and any family of subalgebras?

Comment: @RobertShore But isn't the empty set and {0}, {1} contained in every intersection of all boolean subalgebras? That's the part that I don't understand.

Comment: Do you think that $A$ (your arbitrary subalgebra of $B$) is contained in every subalgebra $D$ containing $\varnothing?$

Comment: @AnneBauval ah! Of course A must be contained in D to be a subalgebra of D, the definition didn't say it explicitly so I dind't think of it! To answer your question not always.

Comment: @AnneBauval your last question answered this for me, for if not my dumb question would have made more sense. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So now  gen(∅) = ?

Comment: @AnneBauval it's gotta be the trivial algebra, for is the only one we know for sure is contained in every D, that is {0,1}

Comment: Fine! And same gen(E) for any $E\subseteq\{0,1\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you, now I see it clear!